# Remove a service in ASP.Net Core Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc

In an Asp.Net MVC Core (early versions, versions 1.0 or 1.1), dependency injection bindings are configured as follow in the Startup.cs class :

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddScoped<IMyService, MyService>();
        // ...
    }
}
```

In my applications, I usually have a base Startup class, where generic bindings are defined as a sequence of these lines :

```
public abstract class BaseStartup
{
    public virtual void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddScoped<IMyService1, MyService1>();
        services.AddScoped<IMyService2, MyService2>();
    }
}
```

Then in my application, I inherit the startup class, and inject other services as well :

```
public class Startup : BaseStartup
{
    public override void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        base.ConfigureServices(services);

        services.AddScoped<IMyService3, MyService3>();
        services.AddScoped<IMyService4, MyService4>();
    }
}
```

I now wonder : how can I kind of 'override' a previous binding ?
I would like, for instance, to either remove, or modify a binding defined in the base class, like :

```
services.Remove<IMyService1>(); // Doesn't exist
services.AddScoped<IMyService1, MyBetterService1>();
```

Or simply update the binding :

```
services.AddScoped<IMyService1, MyBetterService1>(replacePreviousBinding: true); // Doesn't exist either !
```

Is there a way to do that ? Or maybe simply declaring a new binding with the same interface as a previously defined binding will override that binding ?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

You can use normal collection API to remove your services:

```
services.AddScoped<IService>();

var serviceDescriptor = services.FirstOrDefault(descriptor => descriptor.ServiceType == typeof(IService));
services.Remove(serviceDescriptor);
```

Also you can create extension methods to achieve the same:

```
public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection Remove<T>(this IServiceCollection services)
    {
        if (services.IsReadOnly)
        {
            throw new ReadOnlyException($"{nameof(services)} is read only");
        }

        var serviceDescriptor = services.FirstOrDefault(descriptor => descriptor.ServiceType == typeof(T));
        if (serviceDescriptor != null) services.Remove(serviceDescriptor);

        return services;
    }
}
```

Comment: This sounds perfect, and is exactly what I need. When I thought about this approach, I didn't know what "key" should be used, and the serviceDescriptor is then the answer. I wonder why they didn't provide the extension within the framework. I'll upvote you and mark the answer as accepted once I have tested.

Comment: Super, I have tested in locally before publishing the answer so I expect it to work. Maybe they don't consider it as a common case to add those additional methods.

Comment: Ok if you tested, I accept the answer now. Since I need this in a big refactoring task, I am too far from having my code ready to be tested !!

Comment: I have edited your answer to respect the Fluent API style used in these extensions, so that chained calls can be made.

Comment: Makes very good sense.

Comment: Even after I remove something from the ServiceCollection, it is still being injected into constructors that ask for it. I can delete the old one, or add a new one, and the old one is still being injected into constructors.

Comment: @Nick do you replace service at app startup or after the app has started?

Comment: Replaced after app started.

Comment: @Nick ASP.NET Core creates service provider from service collection, so if you change service collection after service provider was created those changes won't take effect. You have to configure your services at app startup.

Comment: A slight mod suggestion to check if the collection is read-only ( after .Build() )

 if (services.IsReadOnly)            {                throw new ReadOnlyException($"{nameof(services)} is read only");            }