# "Restart" singleton service in ASP.Net Core

Tags: c#, service, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc-2.0

I have a couple of services that I inject using DI in an ASP.Net Core App. These services use a couple of writable configuration objects that I also inject using DI. However, as these services need to be singletons, the configuration object is only passed when the service is started, any changes to it will thus not be picked up. So I need to either restart these singletons or somehow get the new `IOptionsSnapshot` passed into them.

To further clarify, here is my code:

Startup.cs:

```
//Inject service and config object
services.ConfigureWritable<DataSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("DataSettings"));
services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, DataService>();
```

DataService.cs:

```
public DataService(IOptionsSnapshot<DataSettings> data)                   
{
    //_options is used to configure the service
    this._options = data.Value;
}
```

DataController.cs:

```
public DataController(IWritableOptions<DataSettings> data)
{
    _data = data;
}

[HttpPost("conf/data/new")]
public void InsertData([FromBody] IEnumerable<ModuleSettings> newData)
{
    var data = _data.Value.Data.ToList();
    data.AddRange(newData.ToList());
    _data.Update(d => d.Data = data.ToArray());
}
```

As you can see, I set up my service with a config object in *Startup.cs*. Then I pass the config object to both my service and a controller used for configuring the service. The Interface `IWritableOptions` is derived from `IOptionsSnapshot` and can be used to write back the changes to *appsettings.json*. This all works, however, when I make changes to my configuration object and update *appsettings.json*, the changes do not get passed into my service. It would be overkill to restart the whole application so I am looking for a way to just restart that one service or somehow set the config object in it. I can't expose the `_options` property of the service because these services are configured dynamically so there could be 2, 3, etc. running in the background.

Comment: Config and Options have a change notification system you should look into.

Answer (score 4):

Some ideas that may help:

1. Are you sure your service *needs* to be a singleton? Most of the time, a data access service like this doesn't, and can instead be made Scoped (1 instance per web request). This would eliminate your problem if you can support it.
2. Instead of passing in an IOptionsSnapshot, you could pass in IOptions or some custom OptionsReader type you would create, which would actively read the *current* value from configuration via a method. Call this method from your singleton service and you should be able to get the current connection details for any given call.
3. Modify your service to accept its connection details as part of its method signature. Not ideal, as you'd probably need to add it to many methods, but it would accomplish your goal.
4. I haven't tried it, but you can probably replace (or remove) the singleton service in the services collection at runtime (after startup). If you removed it any time an update was made to config, a new one would be created the next time one was requested. Here is a related answer that shows how to do this from within Startup: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42946802/13729

Comment: last option helped me when a scoped service was having performance issues especially with a very transactional DB component service which needed a configuration update very rarely