# How to disable builtin logger for .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, logging

I am using log4net

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(options => {
    options.UseInMemoryDatabase("bjsports");
});

builder.Logging.AddLog4Net("log4net.config");

builder.Services.AddHostedService<SportsbookEventService>();
builder.Services.AddHostedService<SportsbookEventService1>();
//builder.Services.AddHostedService<SportEventService>();

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

My appsettings

```json
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=localhost; Initial Catalog=bjsports"
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

And then my log4net config

```
<log4net>
  <root>
    <level value="WARN" />
    <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
  </root>
  <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
    <param name="Threshold" value="INFO" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%date [%thread] %level %logger - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
  </appender>
</log4net>
```

However, in my logging:

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: https://localhost:7008
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5008
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: XXX
warn: <MYCLASS>[0]
      XXX
2022-06-11 09:20:25,055 [32] WARN XXX
warn: <MYCLASS>[0]
      XXX
2022-06-11 09:20:25,212 [32] WARN XXX
```

I am getting log4net output as well as a copy of my logs into the built in logger.  How do I  make it so my logs only get output to log4net and not the built in logger?

Edit - added more to the main to show entire code.

Comment: Show us your full `ConfigureServices` and `Main` methods, and your `HostBuilder` logic.

Comment: @Dai I have added my entire `Program.cs` file.

Comment: `2022-06-11 09:20:25,212 [32] WARN XXX` This is a log entry from log4net that I have specifically declared as `ConsoleAppender`.    `warn: <MYCLASS>[0]
      XXX` This log entry is coming from some default logger in .net core.  So when I log something `logger.LogWarning("XXX")` it gets logged twice, once to my `ConsoleAppender` and once to this built in logger.

Comment: IIRC, the `WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);` method will add the `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging` default log factory - but you can remove it with  `ServiceCollection.Remove(...)` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42945859/remove-a-service-in-asp-net-core-dependency-injection)), however I'm unsure what exact service interfaces to search for.

Comment: @Dai Thanks!  Your comment helped me fine this `builder.Services.AddLogging(c => c.ClearProviders());` which was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can ignore default logging factory in asp.net core services with ClearProviders extension method on ILoggingBuilder :

```
builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
```

So you should first clear default providers then register your logger provider as follow:

```
builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Logging.AddLog4Net("log4net.config");
```